# Diagram section doesn't open Data Grip Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql, database, intellij-idea, datagrip

I use ubuntu and DataGrip 2019.3.3. I created a database named personal_web with its tables. When I want to plot diagrams from the diagram section, this section is disabled to me and nothing is showing or opening. In addition, when I click on the Diagram section, it seems it's disabled and the click doesn't work. I search a lot but I couldn't find an answer. Note that I create all my tables using console and commands. I didn't create the database with GUI. My screen picture is attached.[image: data grip]

Comment: The same happens if you invoke the context menu on a persona schema?

Comment: yes this is happened wherever I tried

Comment: Try ctrl-shift-a (Find action) and then type Diagram. The same result? If yes, please report it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: nothings changed ok  i will report it